# Getting geom_tile to draw square rather than rectangular cells

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm trying to generate a `heatmap` plot using `ggplot`'s `geom_tile`. My data have far more rows than columns.

```
  set.seed(1)
  df <- data.frame(val=rnorm(100),gene=rep(letters[1:20],5),cell=c(sapply(LETTERS[1:5],function(l) rep(l,20))))
```

Running:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(y=gene,x=cell,fill=val))+geom_tile(color="white")
```

produces:
[image]

How do I get the `heatmap` cells to be of symmetric dimensions - squares instead of rectangles (height=width)? without distorting the dimensions of the figure.

Answer (score 43):

An option is to add `coord_equal`.

> The default, ratio = 1, ensures that one unit on the x-axis is the
>   same length as one unit on the y-axis

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = gene, x = cell, fill = val)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Tweak the ratio as follows

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(val=rnorm(100),gene=rep(letters[1:20],5),
             cell=c(sapply(LETTERS[1:5],function(l) rep(l,20))))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df,aes(y=gene,x=cell,fill=val))+geom_tile(color="white")
p <- p + coord_fixed(ratio = 0.7)
p
```

[image]

Comment: But if my actual data has many more rows: df <- data.frame(val=rnorm(500),gene=rep(1:100,5),cell=c(sapply(LETTERS[1:5],function(l) rep(l,100)))), this shrinks the figure tremendously.

Comment: But…you _want_ squares. I'm not sure how you plan on getting squares without a long plot. You could `coord_flip()` it (I'd swap the x & y before trying that, though, since it's the same thing and easier to remember). OR you could partition it into 2, 3, 4 plots but keep the same color scale.