# ggplot Heatmap make cells square with unkown number of unique y-values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know there is at least one very similar question here:
[Getting geom_tile to draw square rather than rectangular cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859438/getting-geom-tile-to-draw-square-rather-than-rectangular-cells)

However, I could not figure out how to make it.

I have this dataframe:

```
structure(list(fake_date = structure(c(18331, 18333, 18334, 18338, 
18339, 18340, 18341, 18345, 18346, 18347, 18348, 18352, 18353, 
18354, 18355, 18358, 18359, 18360, 18361, 18366, 18367, 18368, 
18369, 18372, 18373, 18374, 18375, 18376, 18379, 18380, 18381, 
18382, 18386, 18387, 18388, 18389, 18390, 18393, 18394, 18395, 
18397, 18400, 18402, 18404, 18407, 18410, 18415, 18421, 18425, 
18428, 18431, 18436, 18451, 18473, 18480, 18501, 18526, 18535, 
18540, 18543, 18549, 18555, 18563, 18568, 18576, 18582, 18591, 
18592, 18604, 18607, 18609, 18610, 18612, 18617, 18619, 18266, 
18280, 18290, 18293, 18302, 18308, 18311, 18314, 18324, 18325, 
18329, 18337, 18340, 18343, 18344, 18352, 18353, 18358, 18373, 
18378, 18392, 18409, 18445, 18484, 18567, 18581, 18584, 18592, 
18596, 18598, 18605, 18609, 18617, 18268, 18278, 18285, 18308, 
18310, 18338, 18358), class = "Date"), year = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022), q = c(18.8, 20.5, 15.1, 17.8, 23.5, 22.5, 17.2, 
16.2, 20.4, 20.3, 17.4, 17.4, 17.2, 19.2, 15.1, 11.8, 16.5, 18.1, 
21.6, 18.1, 18.9, 21.2, 15.1, 12, 13.2, 16.3, 19.9, 17.8, 12.6, 
15.1, 19.4, 20, 12.5, 16.1, 10, 20.5, 12.8, 11.5, 15.9, 17.2, 
12.8, 11.3, 14.4, 15, 10.5, 19.2, 14.6, 9.9, 14.5, 12.2, 17.6, 
14.4, 7.7, 21.3, 18.2, 16.8, 11.8, 11.4, 10.2, 20.6, 16.8, 17, 
19.8, 13.7, 17.7, 15.1, 12.7, 15, 16.6, 17.5, 31.4, 14, 14.8, 
11.4, 14.6, 19.2, 19.2, 14.4, 11.6, 16.4, 16, 11.6, 10.5, 16.8, 
16.5, 14.6, 17.6, 13.3, 15, 17.4, 13.8, 15.4, 18.1, 17.4, 13.8, 
12.4, 19.5, 9, 16.5, 10.5, 11.5, 20.3, 17, 15.5, 22.7, 21.5, 
11.6, 17.3, 17.6, 10.4, 11.2, 15.2, 16.1, 19.2, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-115L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

which looks like this:

```
  fake_date   year     q
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-03-10  2020  18.8
2 2020-03-12  2020  20.5
3 2020-03-13  2020  15.1
4 2020-03-17  2020  17.8
5 2020-03-18  2020  23.5
6 2020-03-19  2020  22.5
```

I want to plot the `fake_date` on the x-axis and the `year` (numeric in this case but could be a factor) on the y-axis. I also want to fill the boxes with the `q` column.
So I tried to do this (knowing that it would not work):

```
ggplot(df, aes(fake_date, year)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=q))
```

[image]

So I figured I should use the `coord_equal` coordinate system and set a value ratio.
But I just cant figure out how to set it. I also would prefer to not set a fixed value, because the number of unique values on the y-axis (the number of unique years) might vary.

Comment: But if your tiles are square, your chart would be over 100 times wider than it is tall. It might work if you are able to do months, or conceivably even weeks, but having all the days in a year as squares will only work if you wrap them round. There are many ways to do this in R - see for example https://r-charts.com/evolution/calendar-heatmap/

Answer (score 0):

This is very easily done in ggplot with `coord_fixed(ratio = 1)`.

**Example**

```
ggplot(df, aes(fake_date, year)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=q)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio=1)
```

**Full documentation**

https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/ggplot2/html/coord_fixed.html